# Why the colors is not changing on the half way when spinning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 targetRotation;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float duration;
    public Light[] lights;
    public GameObject material;

    private Material _material;

    // 0,31,191
    // 255,0,0

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _material = material.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));

        var c = Color.Lerp(new Color(255, 0, 0), new Color(0, 31, 191), 0.5f);
        _material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", c);
    }
}
```

The original color is :

[original color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj1vv.jpg)

The color I want to change it to and then to keep changing between the two colors is :

[The color to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXAam.jpg)

but instead it's just making white color.
in both sides it's just white.

[just white color it's not changing between the two colors I was setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGKJv.jpg)

Comment: Try using `.sharedMaterial` instead of `.material`. Does that resolve the issue? Also, are you sure you want to change the emission color? That's the color it radiates, not the color it appears.

Comment: @Basic If I'm changing the color in the Main Maps the white color it's not changing what I want. Only if changing the emission color.

Comment: Values needs to be between 0 and 1. That'd be why you get full white.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I understand your problem...

The thing you *actually* want to change is the albedo. That's the colour a material appears.

Unfortunately, as you're already using a texture for your albedo, that's not so simple.

You have a couple of options. The optimal way (performance-wise) is to write a shader that takes your texture and identifies parts of it (eg using a known color key like hot pink) and inserts the fading colour at runtime.

This requires some knowledge of writing shaders but is discussed here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/284747/how-can-i-change-the-colour-of-part-of-a-texture.html

Alternatively, you can "cut out" the bits that need to change colour in the main material by making them transparent.

You can then add a second material to the object, ordered beneath the first. You then change the albedo of this second material and it will be visible through the "holes" in the first.

This approach is discussed here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/395405/color-specific-sections-of-a-texture-1.html

Comment: In the shader in the link after created a shader and copied to it the content from the answer in the link I'm getting error in the editor that there is an error onl ine 57 : parse error syntax error unexpected $end this is the line 55,56,57 ENDCG //Shader End
            }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToRotate = new List<Transform>();
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public Light[] lights;
    public Material material;
    public Vector3 targetAngle = new Vector3(-90f, 0f, 0f);

    private bool resetPos = false;
    private Vector3 currentAngle;

    // 0,31,191
    // 255,0,0

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentAngle = objectsToRotate[0].transform.eulerAngles;

        StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(rotationSpeed == 0 && resetPos == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
            {
                currentAngle = new Vector3(
             Mathf.LerpAngle(currentAngle.x, targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime), 0, 0);

                objectsToRotate[i].transform.eulerAngles = currentAngle;
            }

            resetPos = true;
        }
        else
        {
            resetPos = false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Count; i++)
        {
            objectsToRotate[i].Rotate(new Vector3(Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    public void setHighlight(bool highlight)
    {
        if (highlight)
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(0, 31, 191));
        }
        else
        {
            material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
            material.globalIlluminationFlags = MaterialGlobalIlluminationFlags.RealtimeEmissive;
            material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(255,0,0));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SetTrue()
    {
        setHighlight(true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetFalse());
    }

    IEnumerator SetFalse()
    {
        setHighlight(false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        StartCoroutine(SetTrue());
    }
}
```